# How do I convert plain string to Record<string, string> in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am new to Typescript and I have following question.

I have a plain string with value lets say

`const myStr = "key1=value1,key2=value2"`

Now, I want to convert it into a Record<string, string> whose value would be something like

`myRecord: Record<string, string> = { key1:"value1", key2:"value2" }`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can your keys and values contain commas or equal signs?  If so, are they encoded in some way?  Edge cases like that can really change the applicability of certain approaches to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Split by commas, then for each key-value pair, split them by the equal sign. This is of course, assuming that the key-value pairs themselves don't contain commas or equal signs. The resulting array of pairs can be turned into an object with `Object.fromEntries`.

```
const myStr = "key1=value1,key2=value2";

const result: Record<string, string> = Object.fromEntries(myStr.split(",").map((pair) => pair.split("=")));

console.log(result);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NarO9m)